# Using ostownsville/cordova-plugin-fcm, onNotification() method is not executing on android

Tags: android, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have click_Action: 'FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY' in the message which I am sending from server side still `onNotification()` method is not getting executed on android. I'm gettign push notifications on device but it is not going inside `onNotification()`. It is working fine on ios.

Below are cordova versions in my application.

```
"dependencies": {
"cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
"cordova-google-api-version": "0.0.1",
"cordova-ios": "^4.5.0",
"cordova-plugin-fcm": "git+https://github.com/ostownsville/cordova-plugin-fcm.git",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "2.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "1.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "1.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "~2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "3.2.2",
"cordova-plugin-streaming-media": "^1.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1"
}
```

I have tried all possible solution to get it resolve. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, onNotification() wouldn't fire no matter what I do. 
I finally ended up using [ionic native push](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/) which uses [cordova's push plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) and it worked perfecty.
Below a snippet of what i did 
`const options: PushOptions = {
      android: {
      senderID: '??????'
      },
      ios: {
      alert: 'true',
      badge: false,
      sound: 'true'
      }
    };
    const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);
    pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('device token -> ' + data.registrationId);
    });

    pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('message -> ' + data.message);
    });
    pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin' + error));`